# How to renew Long Lived User Access Token (before its 60 days expiry period)

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I am using the following API to get Long Lived User Access Token

https://graph.facebook.com/v8.0/oauth/access_token.

This long lived token expires after 60 days but we can renew it before 60 days (according to [Facebook Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/refreshing/)).

So I tried this API to get code https://graph.facebook.com/v8.0/oauth/client_code

and then used the code returned by above API to receive a new long lived access token using the following API - https://graph.facebook.com/v8.0/oauth/access_token

But when I checked the newly received token in Access Token Debugger the expiry was exactly same was of previous/old token.

So the Facebook API to review the Long Lived User Access Token is not working. Not getting if I am missing something here or what?

Thanks in advance